# Why does @Storybook/react-native requires react-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, storybook

Why does `@Storybook/react-native` require `react-dom`?

My understanding of `react-dom` is that it is used for the browser. But, since React Native doesn't use a browser this is just a peerDependency that will never be used.

When running a React Native app with remote debugging on, it will use Chrome as the running context and have a DOM available. Is this the reason for using it?

My package.json:

`"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@storybook/react-native": "4.1.1",
    ...
}`

I get these warnings when doing `yarn install`:

    `warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/core@4.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.3.0".
    warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui@4.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@*".
    warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-modal@3.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16".
    warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-treebeard@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0".
    warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-treebeard > velocity-react@1.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer from Github Issue: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/5156

> starting from v5 it won't need it. It is necessary so we could run web part of storybook. But the web part from v5 is going to be opt in

Comment: November 2023 - still getting @storybook/react-native errors related to react-dom